# What are the units for battery temperature and voltage when Intent.BATTERY_ACTION_CHANGED on android device?

Tags: java, android, power-management, temperature

I retrieved battery temperature and voltage information using the intent `Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` and the values I got are pretty weird. I could not get any clue: `temperature=270` and `voltage=3782`!

What are these values? Do they have any units like celsius, fahrenheit or milli or micro volt?

Answer (score 33):

- voltage- int, current battery voltage in millivolts
- temperature - int, current battery temperature in tenths of  a degree Centigrade

From [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/BatteryService.java).

Comment: what is tenths of a degree centigrade?? how to convert it to celcius?

Comment: @AshokJeev, you divide it by 10 because there are 10 tenths in an unit: `temperature_C = (float) ( intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0) / 10);`

Comment: Celcius is the same as centigrade. Mr. Celcius, who invented that temperature scale wanted it named centigrage, but it is also called Celcius since his death.