# Getting the Battery temperature and unit of the result

Tags: android, battery, units-of-measurement, temperature

I was reading how to [get the temperature of the battery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997289/get-temperature-of-battery-on-android) and I make small app, and in my receiver I have something like this

```
int temp = intent.getIntExtra("temperature", 0);
```

well , this temp have values like 390 or 380 something that is really big to be Celsius but I think that is big number even for Fahrenheit...

can someone please tall what is the unit, does it have a range and so on.

in the official documentation all I found was "integer containing the current battery temperature"

Thanks

Comment: Tempature is tenths of a degree Centigrade see:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860415/what-are-the-units-for-battery-temperature-and-voltage-when-intent-battery-action

Comment: please add 1/10 of centigrade as answer so I can close this thread, and thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The temperature is in tenths of a degree centigrade.  Also discussed in question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860415/what-are-the-units-for-battery-temperature-and-voltage-when-intent-battery-action).

Answer (score 1):

the result is 1/10 of the value you get from the intent it means if you get 380 it is 38 degrees.