# Insert point in a number - Android

Tags: java, android, numbers, batterymanager

I've been creating a Battery Status on Android, but the Temperature and the Voltage doesn't come with the Battery Manager, for Example:

I need 28.7ºC, but Battery Manager get 287ºC, in Voltage I need 4.357, but it get 4357, so how do i get this number and insert the point that I need? Thanks!

My code is:

```
int temperature = intent.getIntExtra("temperature", -1);
int voltage = intent.getIntExtra("voltage", -1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
double temperature = intent.getIntExtra("temperature", -1) / 10;
double voltage = intent.getIntExtra("voltage", -1) / 1000;
```

As per [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860415/what-are-the-units-for-battery-temperature-and-voltage-when-intent-battery-actio), unit of measurement are "Tenth of centigrade" and "Millivolts" respectively for temperature and voltage in BatteryManager

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by `DecimalFormat`

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00"); // Set your desired format here.
System.out.println(df.format(temperature/10.0)); // Testing result
```

Answer (score 0):

`int` variables doesn't support floating point. You need to use either `double` or `float` variables.

Answer (score 0):

Well, then divide them:

```
float temperature = intent.getIntExtra("temperature", -1)/10;
float voltage = intent.getIntExtra("voltage", -1)/1000;
```